# Change lightness of a color so that a minimum contrast ratio is met

Tags: colors

Given the following inputs:

- **color**: Black (rgb(0,0,0))
- **contrastRatio**: 7.0

I would like to modify the lightness of `color` so that a contrast ratio of `contrastRatio` exists between the new brightened/darkened color and the original.

In the above case, a lightness of 0.585 should be set on black in order to meet the `7.0` contrast ratio.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: How do you define contrast ratio? The contrast ration is about the new colour compared to the old one (and not compared to a reference colour) right?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, that's correct

Comment: I would convert colours to HSL/HSV and adapting luminance (L or V) according your rules (below a threshold, I would increase L, else I would decrease L), and then convert back to RGB. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Color_conversion_formulae on how to convert colour models

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi My understanding of luminance was wrong. What I should've been altering was the colour's lightness (L) as you described. So now I modify the lightness by a 'step value' (e.g. 0.05) until a minimum contrast is met. This works, but requires multiple iterations of color manipulation to reach this final value. Ideally, a formula would be better

Comment: What about dividing luminance by `7.0`? I do not know what it is your "contrastRatio". It depends on how it is calculated. You may use several formula to calculate contrast

Comment: I've updated OP to reflect use of 'lightness' rather than 'luminance'

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I use chroma-js library, which I believe uses the formula described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html

Answer (score 0):

You use formula 1 of https://w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html

> L = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B where R, G and B are defined as:
>
> - <s>if R_sRGB <= 0.03928 then R = R_sRGB /12.92 else</s> R = ((R_sRGB +0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
> - <s>if G_sRGB <= 0.03928 then G = G_sRGB /12.92 else</s> G = ((G_sRGB +0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
> - <s>if B_sRGB <= 0.03928 then B = B_sRGB /12.92 else</s> B = ((B_sRGB +0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
>
> and R_sRGB, G_sRGB, and B_sRGB are defined as:
>
> - R_sRGB = R_8bit /255
> - G_sRGB = G_8bit /255
> - B_sRGB = B_8bit /255
>
> The "^" character is the exponentiation operator.

so you get the R. No need to use the special case of very dark colours: it is wrong for our cases (and for most cases).

Then you divide R, G, B by 7.0 (really you can do better with the `(L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05)` formula (formula in point 3). This is simple maths.

And now you apply the inverse formula to get R_sRGB, G_sRGB, and B_sRGB. and then you multiply the 3 channels with 255. You can optimize calculations.

In this manner you have the new colour with higher contrast, but you keep hue and saturation.

I use *divide*, assuming you want darker colour, but you can do with multiply for brighter colour, and probably you should find a threshold where you can go down or up.

It is easy maths, just you should keep in mind you should multiply linear R, G, B with the same factor to keep hue/saturation constant, and to forget very dark exception on gamma (if you use it, you get wrong colour: it is just a trick for displays, but it should usually not be used, and never in this case, where you apply again the inverse transformation.